# Optimizing star profile (gaussian) fitting algorithm

Tags: python, scipy

I need to fit several thousand 2D gaussian functions to star profiles (14x14 pixel blocks) on CCD image and get centroid coordinates, FWHM over long and short axes and angle of rotation of the long axis. The problem is that my current code takes too long to execute. Several 10s of seconds on i7 processor and I need it to make much faster. Preferably as fast as possible. I tested several gaussian fitting functions and it appears that the one used in AsPyLib is the fastest http://www.aspylib.com/doc/aspylib_fitting.html
Below is the code that I'm trying to make run faster. Profiling showed that most of the time is spent inside mplfit function.So my question is if this can be accelerated? I tried cythonizing the code but it provided really minor boost. Calculating moments (10x faster) is not suitable for many images that I have due to noise issues which make estimates unreliable. And probably due to the fact that star profiles are often far from being gaussian due to aberrations.
Multiprocessing wasn't a solution either as new process creation overhead was too high for fitting just 1 star profile.
Any ideas where to look further?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

def fit_gauss_elliptical(xy, data):
    """
    ---------------------
    Purpose
    Fitting a star with a 2D elliptical gaussian PSF.
    ---------------------
    Inputs
    * xy (list) = list with the form [x,y] where x and y are the integer positions in the complete image of the first pixel (the one with x=0 and y=0) of the small subimage that is used for fitting.
    * data (2D Numpy array) = small subimage, obtained from the full FITS image by slicing. It must contain a single object : the star to be fitted, placed approximately at the center.
    ---------------------
    Output (list) = list with 8 elements, in the form [maxi, floor, height, mean_x, mean_y, fwhm_small, fwhm_large, angle]. The list elements are respectively:
    - maxi is the value of the star maximum signal,
    - floor is the level of the sky background (fit result),
    - height is the PSF amplitude (fit result),
    - mean_x and mean_y are the star centroid x and y positions, on the full image (fit results), 
    - fwhm_small is the smallest full width half maximum of the elliptical gaussian PSF (fit result) in pixels
    - fwhm_large is the largest full width half maximum of the elliptical gaussian PSF (fit result) in pixels
    - angle is the angular direction of the largest fwhm, measured clockwise starting from the vertical direction (fit result) and expressed in degrees. The direction of the smallest fwhm is obtained by adding 90 deg to angle.
    ---------------------
    """

    #find starting values
    dat=data.flatten()  
    maxi = data.max()
    floor = np.ma.median(dat)
    height = maxi - floor
    if height==0.0:             #if star is saturated it could be that median value is 32767 or 65535 --> height=0
        floor = np.mean(dat)
        height = maxi - floor

    mean_x = (np.shape(data)[0]-1)/2
    mean_y = (np.shape(data)[1]-1)/2

    fwhm = np.sqrt(np.sum((data>floor+height/2.).flatten()))
    fwhm_1 = fwhm
    fwhm_2 = fwhm
    sig_1 = fwhm_1 / (2.*np.sqrt(2.*np.log(2.)))
    sig_2 = fwhm_2 / (2.*np.sqrt(2.*np.log(2.)))    

    angle = 0.

    p0 = floor, height, mean_x, mean_y, sig_1, sig_2, angle

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #fitting gaussian
    def gauss(floor, height, mean_x, mean_y, sig_1, sig_2, angle):

        A = (np.cos(angle)/sig_1)**2. + (np.sin(angle)/sig_2)**2.
        B = (np.sin(angle)/sig_1)**2. + (np.cos(angle)/sig_2)**2.
        C = 2.0*np.sin(angle)*np.cos(angle)*(1./(sig_1**2.)-1./(sig_2**2.))

        #do not forget factor 0.5 in exp(-0.5*r**2./sig**2.)    
        return lambda x,y: floor + height*np.exp(-0.5*(A*((x-mean_x)**2)+B*((y-mean_y)**2)+C*(x-mean_x)*(y-mean_y)))

    def err(p,data):
        return np.ravel(gauss(*p)(*np.indices(data.shape))-data)

    p = leastsq(err, p0, args=(data), maxfev=200)
    p = p[0]

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #formatting results
    floor = p[0]
    height = p[1]
    mean_x = p[2] + xy[0]
    mean_y = p[3] + xy[1]

    #angle gives the direction of the p[4]=sig_1 axis, starting from x (vertical) axis, clockwise in direction of y (horizontal) axis
    if np.abs(p[4])>np.abs(p[5]):

        fwhm_large = np.abs(p[4]) * (2.*np.sqrt(2.*np.log(2.)))
        fwhm_small = np.abs(p[5]) * (2.*np.sqrt(2.*np.log(2.))) 
        angle = np.arctan(np.tan(p[6]))

    else:   #then sig_1 is the smallest : we want angle to point to sig_y, the largest

        fwhm_large = np.abs(p[5]) * (2.*np.sqrt(2.*np.log(2.)))
        fwhm_small = np.abs(p[4]) * (2.*np.sqrt(2.*np.log(2.))) 
        angle = np.arctan(np.tan(p[6]+np.pi/2.))

    output = [maxi, floor, height, mean_x, mean_y, fwhm_small, fwhm_large, angle]
    return output
```

Comment: Have you considered using PyPy? Most of Numpy is supported now.

Comment: I actually didn't. The software I'm writing is designed to help my fellow amateur astronomers to analyze their astrophotos and I don't want them to go through the pain of installing pypy with all the extensions (numpy,scipy,pyqt and few others) while with regular python you can just install anaconda/python(x,y) and have everything needed.

Comment: I'd definitely consider using it. It could be an order of magnitude faster with minimal changes to your algorithm.

Comment: Multiprocessing does not have to be done inefficiently. Start a pool with a fixed number of processes, and feed in stars in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this method before but not implemented it:

http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v9/n7/full/nmeth.2071.html

Might be worth a look as a short-cut method. There is even code to copy on his website http://physics-server.uoregon.edu/~raghu/particle_tracking.html

Comment: @kexxos Thanks! Interesting article but it deals with radially symmetrical spots and finds only particle center, while I'm looking for three additional parameters -  two sigmas and rotation angle.